# Как запустить проект на Vue на сервере?

Tags: vue.js, сервер, frontend

У меня есть проект на Vue, мне нужно его залить на сервер и запустить, я почитал, что нужно перевести проект в обычный html с js. Запустил команду npm run build. Создалась папка dist. Потом я узнал что, чтобы запустить это папку на сервере должен стоять npm, но тк сервер не мой у меня нет прав на него что-либо устанавливать. Вопрос - как мне запустить свой проект Vue  на сервере где нет npm?

Comment: «на сервере должен стоять npm» — зачем? Если это и в самом деле «обычный html с js», то достаточно просто открыть соответствующий html-файл на сайте через браузер

Comment: я открывал на своем компе, открывается просто белый экран. А вообще я вычитал это в документации Vue, что нужно ввести npm install -g serve, но npm  у меня нет возможности поставить

Comment: Значит откройте в браузере инструменты разработчика и разберитесь, с чем связано появление белого экрана

Comment: serve — это всего лишь программа веб-сервер, который точно так же будет просто отдавать браузеру файлы из dist. Если на сервере уже установлен какой-то веб-сервер (а с вероятностью 99% там уже стоит apache2 и/или nginx), то ставить второй веб-сервер абсолютно бессмысленно